# Blank index.php with no errors (EE 2.8.1)

Tags: ee2, config

I am new to EE (but familiar with PHP, SQL, etc.) and am trying to run an EE site locally that was originally made by another developer. It is a large, complex site with numerous plug-ins.

EE verson is 2.8.1. My local setup is Windows 7 64-bit and MAMP with PHP 5.5.38 (the same version the site was built for) and MySQL 5.6.34.

I have imported the db, changed the config file to use my own disk paths etc., and installed further requisites with PHP Composer.

Now, when I visit index.php, I get a completely blank page. I have confirmed that index.php runs to completion (by adding a test 'echo' statement at the end), but it produces no output, even with $debug=1, and I see nothing in the Apache and PHP error logs. (I've also noticed that, when I visit the EE control panel, I can log in, but the CSS styles are all missing.)

I suspect I may have missed something in the config file, problem but am unsure what to try next. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like your paths are not correct. You need to add right path for  theme and template folder.

Comment: In environment.php: ENV_LIVE_SITE_URL = http://localhost/millweb/  ENV_SITE_URL = http://localhost/millweb/  ENV_PATH = C:/MAMP/htdocs/millweb  ENV_ENVIRONMENT = dev   And I also had to add this, to fix errors with extensions not loading: $assign_to_config['third_party_path'] = 'C:/MAMP/htdocs/millweb/third_party';  I believe remaining (CSS) problem is with Theme path. I set it to correct "C:/MAMP/htdocs/millweb/themes/", but still no CSS in control panel: that HTML uses "/themes/filename".  It should be "/millweb/themes/filename".  How/where can I fix that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it in the end. The problem was a missing slash / at the end of the "third_party_path" config setting.